# Two-sided print PDF created by MPDF

Tags: printing, mpdf

I use to generate PDF library mPDF. It is possible to set two-sided printing? The documentation I can not find anything.

My PDF ( http://fotbal.zylacup.cz/zapis-pdf.php?id=2777&hash=f0dc249a48f349874f7dfa9a8c4b6998 )

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The two sided printing would be a printing option, you can't define it in the PDF file.

Comment: It seems indeed that I was kind of wrong. You can't force a document to be printed both sides but you can define **Print Dialog Presets**.
These will define the printing dialog default options but these options can still be changed by the user. 
Anyway, mPDF doesn't seem to be able to change these options, you would need softwares like Adobe Acrobat.